# {INS-08101] Database Configuration Assistant

Tags: oracle

I am getting the following error when I run DBCA (Oracle 18 X):
[INS-08101] - unexpected error while executing the action at state: "summaryPage".
Are you sure you want to continue?  Yes No Cancel
Cause - no additional information available
Action - Contact Oracle Support Services or refer to the software manual
Summary:
-java.lang.NullPointerException

I have tried searching for a response but my Oracle account is a "free" one and does NOT let me search for any errors.

Comment: What's the O/S you are trying to install on?.Did you check installation log files?.

Comment: Window10 64-bit...I did check the log file  How can I attach it? It is a very long file.

Comment: [Post](https://pastebin.com/) here and link in your post

Answer (score 0):

Suresh:
Here is a Pastebin link showing the last part of DBCA log file.
`

```
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.util.exception.AbstractErrorAdvisor:5038
[progressPage.flowWorker] [ 2021-04-12 16:14:05.139 EDT ] [AssistantLogHandler.publish:465]  ---# Begin Stacktrace #---------------------------
ID: oracle.install.commons.util.exception.AbstractErrorAdvisor:5038
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBCreationBeanMapper.mapBeans(DBCreationBeanMapper.java:159)
    at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBCreationBeanMapper.mapBeans(DBCreationBeanMapper.java:127)
    at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigDriver.prepareJob(DBConfigDriver.java:455)
    at oracle.assistants.common.base.driver.AssistantConfigDriver.setup(AssistantConfigDriver.java:202)
    at oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigDriver.setup(DBConfigDriver.java:477)
    at oracle.assistants.common.action.AssistantConfigAction$StepRunner.call(AssistantConfigAction.java:58)
    at oracle.assistants.common.action.AssistantConfigAction$StepRunner.call(AssistantConfigAction.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

---# End Stacktrace #-----------------------------

SEVERE: Apr 12, 2021 4:14:05 PM oracle.assistants.common.base.util.AssistantAdvisor logMessage
SEVERE: [ 2021-04-12 16:14:05.139 EDT ] [FATAL] java.lang.NullPointerException


INFO: Apr 12, 2021 4:20:50 PM oracle.install.commons.util.exception.AbstractErrorAdvisor advise
INFO: Advice is ABORT


SEVERE: Apr 12, 2021 4:20:50 PM oracle.install.commons.util.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler handleException
SEVERE: Unconditional Exit


INFO: Apr 12, 2021 4:20:50 PM oracle.install.commons.util.ExitStatusSet add
INFO: Adding ExitStatus FAILURE to the exit status set`https://pastebin.com/X4965dDU
```

Murray